# WooCommerce - Maximum qty per line per product

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WordPress site using Woo-commerce as the shop.  We want to be able to set some maximum limits for each product so that if someone wants to order 40 of Product A, but we have set Product A to have a maximum limit of 30, the user will be able to order two lines of Product A, one for 30 and one for 10.

The max qty limit per product is just per line.  The customer can have as many as they want in total but limited to the maximum quantity per order line.

I have tried quite a few plugins, the max qty one and the max and min quantities ones but these limit the quantities for the entire order rather than just by line.  The shipping plugins I have looked at can't change the quantities per line and instead look at the overall quantity to determine shipping costs.  Neither of these approaches are what we are after.

Does anyone know of a plugin/method to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, the maximum qty per line is the number of that product per shipping pallet, so the customer can order more than that, but the volume pricing restarts for the second pallet.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Does anyone know if this would even be possible in WooCommerce?